# Cannot Iterate through JSON object given from code behind

Tags: asp.net, json, vb.net

I am trying to read out a JSON data which is given from the function in code behind. I have this set up:

Code behind:

```
    <WebMethod()>
Public Shared Function LoadVolgNummer(ByVal EnqDGId As String, ByVal VolgordeId As String) As String
    Dim oRetValue As EnqueteVraag = Nothing
    Try
        oRetValue = EnqueteDetail.LoadQuestion(EnqDGId, VolgordeId)
    Catch ex As Exception
        ReportError(ex.Message, GetCurrentMethod.Name)
    End Try
    Dim serializer As New JavaScriptSerializer
    Dim JSON As String = serializer.Serialize(oRetValue).ToArray
    Return JSON
End Function
```

This is the JSON string I get back from my function:

```
{"questionid":1,"question":"De dienstverlening van xxx in het algemeen"}
```

JQUERY on page:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "enquete.aspx/LoadVolgNummer",
        data: JSON.stringify({EnqDGId: '1', VolgordeId: '1'}),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            alert(msg.question);
        },
        error:function() {
            alert('failure in loading volgnummer')
        }
    });
```

Enquetevraag class:

```
Public Class EnqueteVraag

Public questionid As Integer
Public question As String
```

End Class

The result is a success but I just can't read out the data in jQuery. It shows me 'undefined'. Any help is appreciated.

Kind regards

Comment: If the response is as shown, `msg.Vraag` should be the question text. Please use lowerCase property names, however. Ideally, in english.

Comment: I updated it in english. THe problem is however I dont get the question text but I get 'undefined' with my alert. The JSON string is what is about to be send back to the page (return JSON).

Comment: What does `alert(typeof msg);` show you?

Comment: @Felix is says: object

Comment: @Kaizer "about to be sent back", or what actually arrives? If this isn't what the browser receives, javascript is not to blame here, and the question needs to be retagged to attract people who can speak the server-side language (VB.net?)

Comment: Then do `console.log(msg)`, have a look at the object and make sure the property you are trying to access really exists. If you are trying to access a non-existing property you will get `undefined`.

Comment: Please check what the server actually sends: open the browser console, switch to the network tab, make the request and click to open the request for details.

Comment: @ Jan: I updated the tags. thanks for pointing it out

@Felix: This is the result (a correct one imo):
Object {d: "{"questionid":1,"question":"De dienstverlening van Sodiwe"}

Comment: The object seems to have only **one** property `d`, whose value is a string containing JSON (so you generated double-encoded JSON somehow). `JSON.parse(msg.d).question` should work but it's pretty ugly. The real solution is to fix your server side code to generate the proper output.

Comment: That's it Felix !! Thanks for the help ! Also thanks for Jan for looking into it.
Cheers guys

Comment: I will look into my server code to alter some because it is indeed ugly. Thanks !

Comment: And, to determine why is the output as it is, there's not enough information in this question. Perhaps include the `EnqueteVaarg` code if you want us to look at it.

Comment: well the class is simple because I wanted to test it first. It's updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case closed thanks to Felix King and Jan Dvorak !

JSON.parse(msg.d).question

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function getQuestions()
{
   var jsonData = $.ajax({
         url: "enquete.aspx/LoadVolgNummer",
         data: JSON.stringify({EnqDGId: '1', VolgordeId: '1'}),
        dataType: "json",
        async: false
    }).responseText;
    jsonData = JSON.parse(jsonData);
    alert(jsonData.question);
}
```